# How to Redirect particular url to homepage instead of redirecting to 404 using gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, strapi

I have one url for example **mysite.com?utm_source=fb** when user trigger this url need to redirect to home page. i have tried client-side-redirect plugin but didn't worked out

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`onClientEntry` API (from Gatsby browser)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#onClientEntry) to trigger a function once the user enters your site. In your `gatsby-browser.js`:

```
export const onClientEntry = () => checkUtm();
```

`checkUtm()` is your checker function, place it wherever you want and import it in your `gatsby-browser.js`.  The function should look like this:

```
export const checkUtm = ()=>{
    if (typeof window !== "undefined"){
      const queryString = window.location.search;
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
      const fromFb = urlParams.get('utm_source') === "fb";
    
      if(fromFb) navigate("/");
    }
}
```

`typeof window !== "undefined"` condition is important to avoid code-breaking, since, at the compiling time, [`window` (or other global objects) may not be defined yet](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/).

The rest of the code can be manipulated to fit your exact requirements, I've added [`navigate` from Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/) but change it as you need.

> I have one more doubt in the same if i have url ex:
> `mysite.com?utm_source=IwAR1AjzvBHLFOp0CeER8X1XdBgGbLDyK9hDh2dVBe15ZXnWjEAae-C0sT67M`
> like this and every time string will change how to implement

This should work:

```
export const checkUtm = ()=>{
    if (typeof window !== "undefined"){
      const queryString = window.location.search;
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
      const hasUtmSource = urlParams.get('utm_source');
    
      if(hasUtmSource) navigate("/");
    }
}
```

The `const hasUtmSource = urlParams.get('utm_source');` statement will get any value of the `utm_source` parameter so, if it exists, it will validate the next condition, making the `navigate("/")`.

Comment: I have one more doubt in the same if i have url **ex: mysite.com?utm_source=IwAR1AjzvBHLFOp0CeER8X1XdBgGbLDyK9hDh2dVBe15ZXnWjEAae-C0sT67M**  like this and every time string will change how to implement

Comment: You can leave the condition like: `const hasUtmSource = urlParams.get('utm_source')` and `if(hasUtmSource) navigate("/");` this will match everytime the `utm_source`parameter has any value

Comment: Is it possible to redirect irrespective of query parameters. for example : **mysite.com/page1?utm_source=fb** redirect to **mysite.com/page1** and **mysite.com?utm_source=fb** redirect to **mysite.com** like this

Comment: Of course, URL parameters are not handled by `@reach/router` so they will always redirect to the source page. I assume, given the nature of the question (`UTM parameters`) that the users will come outside the project. So if he wants to perform an action once the user lands on his project, he needs to do some actions in `onClientEntry` API, catching those parameters and making some redirections accordingly

Comment: Hi ferran, it worked in my local but getting the same 404 page in uat can you please help me to resolve this

Comment: It's impossible to guess without seeing the platform or the server. It seems something related to this if it works in your local.